# How to put a subtitle for each item of v-radio-button using vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have created a dynamic list of items with v-radiobuttons. What I want to add is a subtitle for each item below them. I have tried some ways but nothing works.
This is the code:

```
 <v-radio-group v-model="institutionSelected">
 <v-radio v-for="(institution, index) in itemInstitutions" 
 :label="institution" :key="index" :value="index"> </v-radio> 
  </v-radio-group>
```

//This is list of subtitles for each item:

```
 <v-list-item-subtitle v-text="itemRoles[index]"></v-list-item-subtitle>
```

I want it to appear like that:

[image: How to look]

But appears like that actually:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to wrap the list items by `v-radio-group` component then loop through `itemInstitutions` using `v-list-item` component and the radio button as list item title :

```
 <v-radio-group v-model="institutionSelected">
  <v-list-item two-line v-for="(institution, index) in itemInstitutions" :key="index">
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title>
            <v-radio :label="institution" :value="index"></v-radio>
            </v-list-item-title>
          <v-list-item-subtitle class="ml-8">{{itemRoles[index]}}</v-list-item-subtitle>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
</v-radio-group>
```

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/PomQGzY)**